# Overcarbination in a Chocolate Porter

Tags: over-carbonation

I brewed a batch of chocolate porter from an all-grain kit.  Not only does the finished product not taste particularly good, but 1/3-1/2 of the beer foams up and out of the bottle once it's opened.

Any thoughts on what could cause this to occur?  I'm thinking maybe I used too much priming sugar, or possibly my equipment wasn't adequately sanitized.

Comment: how much priming sugar did you use? before you bottled did you taste it? or notice anything about how it looked or smelled?

Comment: While I don't remember exactly how much was used, I used only the priming sugar that came in the kit.  I didn't notice any bad smells as I was bottling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of bad flavour and foaming bottles could indicate an infection by wild yeast or bacteria.

From [How to Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com/section4/chapter21-1.html) by John Palmer.

> Gusher Infection However, the sustained bubbling is often due to "gusher type" infection. These infections can occur at any time and are due to wild yeasts or bacteria that eat the higher order sugars, like dextrins. The result in the fermentor is a beer that keeps bubbling until all of the carbohydrates are fermented, leaving a beer that has no body and very little taste. If it occurs at bottling time, the beer will overcarbonate and will fizz like soda pop, fountaining out of the bottle.
>   Cure: Improve your sanitation next time.